# Applications of Dynkin Diagrams in Physics

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, lie-algebra, applied-physics, affine-lie-algebra

I've been studying Dynkin Diagrams for a while, but I can't grasp what are the applications in physics.

Can anyone help me understand where can we use Dynkin Diagrams in particle physics to "solve problems"?

Comment: Dynkin diagrams and group theory appears in almost every area of physics.